# JSFiddle CSS and Result text areas squeezed

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I am using Chrome on OSX and have encountered an infuriating bug which makes JSFiddle unusable:

[image: My unusable JSFiddle]

As the screenshot shows the CSS and Result text areas are squeezed off the screen with no handle to pull them back. **How can I make them visible and usable?**

It hasn't always rendered like this, but I'm not sure what has caused it.

---

## What I've tried

- Disabling all chrome extensions
- Resizing the browser to a ridiculous width
- Clearing local, session and cookie storage for JSFiddle on Chrome
- Removing secondary screens
- Changing my screen resolution

None of which have changed anything.

---

## Update

The bug is not replicated when using safari.

Comment: If you inspect the elements, what are the properties for the "column right"  fieldset ? You could set a min-width there, or on the #panel_css div.

Comment: Did you try in incognito? Seems to be an issue that's been around [for a while](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/226). Not exactly the same issue, but very similar. Maybe inspect the containers and see if they are some ridiculous width, which would point to a JSFiddle bug.

Comment: You can click and drag the little bar that separates the html/JavaScript and css/result side. have u tried that?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=416260 its known issue and hope it would be resolved in next release

Answer (score 0):

very likely you can restore the areas by running
`Layout.setWindowSizes(null)`
from console. it's a well known issue 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388509/jsfiddle-js-panel-size-is-stuck-how-do-i-reset-it